# Using `and_then` how to return Result<(), String>

Tags: rust

I am using [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/2.33.1/clap/struct.Arg.html#method.validator) with a custom validator something like this:

```
.arg(
    Arg::with_name("config")
       .help("config.yml")
       .long("config")
       .default_value("config.yml")
       .short("c")
       .required(true)
       .value_name("FILE")
       .validator(is_file),
    )
```

This is the working validator `is_file` I am using:

```rust
fn is_file(s: String) -> Result<(), String> {
    let metadata = match metadata(&s) {
        Err(err) => return Err(err.to_string()),
        Ok(metadata) => metadata,
    };
    if !metadata.is_file() {
        return Err(format!("cannot read file: {}", s));
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Reading more about [`std::result::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) I found out that it has multiple methods the ones could be used to simplify or reduce significantly the code.

To simplify `is_file` I am trying:

```rust
fn is_file(s: String) -> Result<(), String> {
   metadata(&s).and_then(|m| (!m.is_file()))
}
```

The problem I have is that `!m.is_file()` returns a `bool`:

```
 metadata(&s).and_then(|m| !m.is_file())
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                               |
   |                               expected enum `std::result::Result`, found `bool`
   |                               help: try using a variant of the expected enum: `Ok(!m.i
```

Using `and_then` or other methods from `Result` how could I simplify the `is_file` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `Result` yourself, but you can remove the match statement with the question mark operator and `map_err()`:

```
fn is_file(s: String) -> Result<(), String> {
    if metadata(&s).map_err(|e| e.to_string())?.is_file() {
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(format!("cannot read file: {}", s))
    }
}
```

or with `and_then()` as you suggested:

```
fn is_file(s: String) -> Result<(), String> {
    metadata(&s).map_err(|e| e.to_string()).and_then(|m| {
        if m.is_file() {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(format!("cannot read file: {}", s))
        }
    })
}
```

I'd say it's a matter of taste whether this is better than your original code.

In the future, if there ever is an analogue of [`then_some()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then_some) for `Result`, you might be able to write this without the if-else.